# Android bluethoot with printer adapter

Tags: android, printing, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I have problem.
i have  one bluethoot printer adapter  "Bluetake BT220" and one printer "Star DP8340S".
i want connect my bluetot bt220 to my app android , i have others connections to zebra printers but implemented  the connection.
for this adapter bluethoot, have not connection, looking much the net, I saw that I can connect directly bluethoot.
I can connect to the device but I'm not able to print in the
someone could tell me where I can start?any suggestion is welcome.

any documentation, do not hesitate to ask

thank you all, by  make life easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer to myself.
solved : I've just created a Connection bluethoot follows

```
    bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
                    BluetoothDevice bluetakebt220 = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(obj.getMac().toString());
                    Method m;
                    BluetoothSocket mBTsocket= null;

                        m = bluetakebt220.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket",
                                new Class[] { int.class });
                        // mBTsocket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(bluetakebt220, 1);

                         UUID num = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
                        mBTsocket = bluetakebt220.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(num);
                        mBTsocket.connect();
```

and now just need to print

```
                        String txt ="LINE 1 \n LINE 2 \n";


                        byte[] CPCLFormat = null;
                        try {
                            CPCLFormat = txt .getBytes("utf-8");
                            try {
                                 os.write(CPCLFormat);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                os.close();
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                            CPCLFormat = null;
                            os.close();
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }



                            os.close();
```

I hope that helps, thanks